# HTML5 input types kill jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

The jQuery validation plugin breaks for elements that have a HTML5 type defined.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myform").validate() 
});
...
<form id="myform">
<input id="email" email="true" />
</form>
...
```

Adding the html5 attribute **type="email"** to the input causes the validation to fail. I want to use **type="email"** because mobile phones [use this attribute to display the proper keyboard layout by default](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-email).

What's the best way to achieve both mobile phone friendly keyboards + jquery Validation library?

You can see an example of the issue [here](http://jordanarsenault.com/html5-val-conflict/).

Comment: What percentage of your visitors are you expecting to be on mobile devices?  If it's significant perhaps a mobile version is in order.  Otherwise, it looks like you've found a limitation with the Validation plugin.

Comment: Yes it's significant... 100% ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be able to merge [this pull request](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/pull/108/files) with the main trunk, if you're willing to maintain your own version of the plugin (the patch is quite small and, from a cursory look [at the code](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js), seems like the right thing to do, though it would certainly require testing).

You may also be able to fallback to just using [the HTML5 required](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#required) field (potentially supported by non-javascript-enabled clients), but see [this issue](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/pull/7).

Comment: 1/13/2013: Just meant to add for others looking at a solution that this issue has now been resolved: the Validate plugin now properly validates `type="email"` fields. At the moment of typing this version *1.11.0pre* of the Validate plugin works correctly. Make sure you use the [***latest version of the script***](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js)

Comment: But still is not working with the type "tel". I've done a donation, i hope them to be able to fix this problem..

Answer (score 1):

That problem has already been filed. See this bug report: 
http://plugins.jquery.com/content/html-5-typeemail-prevents-inline-validation-required-email-field

Luckily, there is now a working jQuery plugin for this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/simple_email_validate

Hope it helps. ;)

Comment: Both these links are dead.

Comment: That's because it's from 5 years ago. We now have jQuery Validator for that purpose. :D:D:D:D:D:D:D

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I was just saving other people time.