# Jquery Validate not Working Well with HTML 5?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, jquery-validate, validation

I'm a newbie on Rails and Javascipt.

I've been having trouble using Jquery validate on email fields because of HTML 5 validation blocking jquery validate plugin (the email field gets red outline with no messages). So I have 2 questions.

1.) I have this form (from devise), how do I add novalidate to this?

> = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>
>   registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|

2.) I've also tried adding novalidate using javascript,the email field only gets validated when the form is submitted, not on focus out (which is what I want), but the other field validations are just fine. Does anyone have the same problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the HTML that ends up generating?

Comment: this is the generated html for the haml form, <form id="members" class="member_new" method="post" action="/members" accept-charset="UTF-8">

Comment: If you're using jquery-validate with an HTML "email" field, your probably suffering from the same issue as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234044/html5-input-types-kill-jquery-validation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I got this from the link by ig0774

This solved the problem!

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/pull/108/files

Answer (score 1):

There is [novalidate](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_form_novalidate.asp) attribute:

> The novalidate attribute specifies that the form should not be
>   validated when submitted.

```
form_for(resource, 
         :as => resource_name, 
         :url => 
         registration_path(resource_name), 
         :html => {:novalidate => 'novalidate'}) do |f|
```

Comment: I've tried adding this, but the email field won't validate on focus out, only on form submit..